# Django static files using s3

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am having problems using an s3 bucket for my sites static files.  Currently using django-storages and boto3.

In my setting.py I have:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Running collectstatic sends static files to the s3 bucket successfully, but the static urls in my templates do not update.

I am using apache2 and have not changed the .conf file, do I need to?

Any help would be gratefully recieved

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529912/suspicious-operation-attempted-access-to-denied-while-loading-static-files This was what was causing my issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `but the static urls in my templates do not update.` what did you meant by that, can you try printing the static_url in settings and see if you are getting url what you are expecting, and can you share your template where you are accessing this.

Comment: With debug set to True I can see that the local static files are still being referenced. The path it is looking for is /css/style.css and the error is access denied. As collectstatic works is this an apache2 .conf configuration that I haven’t changed.  If I remove the s3 config and leave it looking locally it works. 

My base template has {% loadstatic%} and static files are presented as Django requires.         Thanks for your help

Comment: Should of been {% load static%}